# shifting the binary numbers in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>    

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int number, result;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> number;
    result = number << 1;
    cout << "Result after bitshifting: " << result << endl; 
}
```

If the user inputs `12`, the program outputs `24`.

In a binary representation, `12` is `0b1100`. However, the result the program prints is `24` in decimal, not `8` (`0b1000`).

Why does this happen? How may I get the result I except?

Comment: Please read the document regarding how to post a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: You can use std::bitset to handle bit level manipulation easily.

Comment: `int` is at least 16 bits (specicifcally, it must be large enough to hold any integer in the ranges of -32,767..32,767 \[signed\] or 0..65,535 \[unsigned\], which requires a minimum of 16 bits), but may be more (it is typically, but not always, 32 bits).  As such, the number that is shifted on standard platforms is generally not `0b1100`, but `0b0000000000001100`.  If you want to treat the number as a 4-digit binary number, you should use `std::bitset` to give you finer control, as @seccpur said above, or a mask, as the answers specify and illustrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why does the program output `24`?**

You are right, `12` is `0b1100` in its binary representation. That being said, it also is `0b001100` if you want. In this case, bitshifting to the left gives you `0b011000`, which is `24`. The program produces the excepted result.

**Where does this stop?**

You are using an `int` variable. Its size is typically 4 bytes (32 bits) when targeting 32-bit. However, it is a bad idea to rely on `int`'s size. Use [stdint.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) when you need specific sizes variables.

**A word of warning for bitshifting over signed types**

Using the `<<` bitshift operator over negative values is undefined behavior. `>>`'s behaviour over negative values is implementation-defined. In your case, I would recommend you to use an `unsigned int` (or just `unsigned` which is the same), because `int` is signed.

**How to get the result you except?**

If you know the size (in bits) of the number the user inputs, you can use a bitmask using the `&` (bitwise AND) operator. e.g.

```
result = (number << 1) & 0b1111; // 0xF would also do the same
```